# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'

Tags: python, module

here's 2 py file

aa.py

```
import bb
b = 3
bb.foo()
```

bb.py

```
import aa
def foo():
    print(aa.b)
```

when run from aa.py,this error came out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyproj\Mytest\src\aa.py", line 7, in <module>
    import bb
  File "D:\pyproj\Mytest\src\bb.py", line 6, in <module>
    import aa
  File "D:\pyproj\Mytest\src\aa.py", line 9, in <module>
    bb.foo()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

## Another episode

just i want to solve the problem but i noticed something interesting or wired

i modified the test

aa.py

```
print('before import bb in aa.py')
import bb
print('after import bb in aa.py')
bb.foo()
print('end of all')
```

bb.py

```
def foo():
    print('before import aa in bb.foo()')
    import aa
    print('after import aa in bb.foo()')
```

start from aa.py

```
before import bb in aa.py
after import bb in aa.py
before import aa in bb.foo()
before import bb in aa.py
after import bb in aa.py
before import aa in bb.foo()
after import aa in bb.foo()
end of all
after import aa in bb.foo()
end of all
```

can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a circular dependency: `aa` imports `bb`, which imports `aa`. Then `aa` calls `bb.foo()`, but this function has not yet been completely defined in `bb`, since the import of `aa` is not completed.

It is better to avoid such complex dependencies. What you can do is pass `aa.b` as an argument to `bb.foo()`:

aa.py

```
import bb
b = 3
bb.foo(b)
```

bb.py

```
def foo(b):
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the circular dependency problem, You should `import aa` in `bb.py` locally not globally:

```
def foo():
    import aa
    print(aa.b)
```